# python s=input().count What does input().count function do in python?

Tags: python, input

I saw this code on the internet:

```
s=input().count
print( max( (s('6')+s('9')+1)//2, max([s(i) for i in "01234578"])))
```

but I don't get what this line does :

```
s=input().count
```

I thought this function was to count how many letters are in the word. So I tried to print the `s`, but I got this error:

```
<built-in method count of str object at 0x7f4f8b859148>
```

what does `input().count` function do and what situation will it be used?

Comment: It's a method, you need to actually call it: `.count()`. And no, it doesn't count how many letters there are in a word. It counts the number of occurrences of a substring, so it actually needs a parameter. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count).

Comment: what does this method do then? could you please explain?

Comment: The method will tell you the count when you call it.

Comment: @hiyum did you read the docs Daniel gave you?

Comment: why so many downvotes for this question? I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s=input().count` is a function which you can call.

You could write

```
input().count('6')
```

to count how many times you get 6 in the `input`.

Or,

```
s('6')
```

is now a shorthand for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input().count
```

Basically you are binding the `count` method to `s` so when you call `s` like `s(i)`, it converts the code to `input().count(i)` internally.

Let me give you a simple example:

```
p = print
p("hello world")

# hello world
```